# JBoss AS 7 can send/receive CDI beans as parameter in remote EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, cdi, weld

I have two applications that communicate with each other via EJB.

And when I try to call a remote EJB passing in parameters a injected value (cdi weld) throws a `ClassNotFoundException` in my bean `com.mycompany.portalcarweb.client.model.User$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy`

If I don't send CDI bean to EJB (sending `new User()` instead), it works normaly.
JBoss can send/receive CDI beans as parameter in remote EJB?

My User.class is in a JBoss module, and I have this module declared in `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` in `WEB-INF` client's folder